# Application deployed on AWS elastic beanstalk is not reachable

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a docker application deployed with elastic beanstalk. Application health is OK. It works and I can access it directly by ec2 instance Public DNS (IPv4). However when I try to access it via URL given by elastic beanstalk I get - "This site can't be reached". Anyone have an idea what the reason could be?

Comment: Can you provide bit more insights on AWS infra architecture being used in Beanstalk. I suspect it's something with the load balancer specifically ports.

Comment: Sure. I have a "classic load balancer" added. It has one listener. port 80 to port 80 (default option). Also by default I have ngix proxy server. Application inside docker run on port 8081

Comment: Found the problem. The application was trying to redirect to https. But there was no listener for 443 in the load balancer. After I've added it, ELB URL works. @vivekyad4v Thanks for a hint